# How to make a script that will make another script in the same folder executable?

Tags: bash, scripts, chmod

How to make a script that will make another script in the same folder executable? I don't want to worry about path since it will be in the same directory. So it should be something like(i'm trying to make D3GO script executable):

```
#!/bin/bash    

chmod +x "$pwd"/D3GO
```

I'm very new to scripts so pls don't laugh :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a `bash` script, all of it's commands run in the directory where the script is invoked from, including `pwd`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
```

If you run this from `/whatever/path`, it will display `/whatever/path`, no matter where the script is placed.

If you want to operate on files in the directory where you are running the script from, you can omit `pwd` like this:

```
chmod +x D3GO
```

This will be interpreted as `chmod +x /whatever/path/D3GO` if you run it from `/whatever/path`, no matter where the script is actually placed.

To operate in the directory where the script is located, you can use the `$BASH_SOURCE` variable. It is an array, and it's first element is the path to the script itself (i.e. `/script/directory/myscript.sh`). You can combine this with the `dirname` command to get just the directory:

```
chmod +x `dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`/D3GO
```

This will look for `D3GO` in the directory where this script is placed instead of where it's invoked from. (Thanks to @muru for pointing out my mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

You were super close!

```
#!/bin/bash    

chmod +x D3GO
```

Comment: You were super close! But this is not what OP asked for. This will look for a file named `D3GO` in the directory you run the script from, not the directory of the script. It will only work as expected if you run the script from it's own directory.

Comment: @kraxor, so how does using `pwd` improve things? It would still look for a script in the directory your running it from.

Comment: @muru you are right, and I was wrong, but for the right reasons. I've updated my answer.